# Does pumping electrolyte solution generate a magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism

A pump is placed within an electrolyte solution, and it pumps the liquid through itself, in the direction of the arrow (see image). Does this movement of electrically charged particles generate a magnetic field?

[image]

Comment: *Does this movement of electrically charged particles generate a magnetic field?* While an electrolyte contains charge carriers, it is also perfectly electrically neutral.

Comment: good point [Comments must be at least 15 characters in length]

Answer (score 1):

@Gert noted that an electrolyte is electrically neutral. However, positive and negative ions in an electrolyte typically have different magnitudes of electrical charge to mass ratios, so movement of an electrolyte in a magnetic field (for example, in the Earth's magnetic field) can lead to partial charge separation and therefore to generation of a current and magnetic field (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excitation_(magnetic)#Self_excitation).

Comment: if the pump works like a reverse turbine, first pushing the liquid out through its sides, to be filled like in the arrow in the image, would the vacuum created also be a voltage gradient and create an electric current?

Comment: @mIna : Sorry, don't have time to sort it out.